# Django project deployment on Vercel got me an error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, vercel, django-apps

I have created a simple blog application using django and postgres database. While I wants to deploy to vercel it throws a different errors like this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGZpC.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5e1w.png)

How can i solve this error?

build_files.sh

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python3.10 manage.py collectstatic
```

vercel.json

````
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "blog/wsgi.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config": {
                "maxLambdaSize": "15mb",
                "runtime": "python3.10"
            }
        },
        {
            "src": "build_files.sh",
            "use": "@vercel/static-build",
            "config": {
                "distDir": "staticfiles_build"
            }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "blog/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}```



I have build_files.sh and vercel.json. I think there is no problem. I also have requirements.txt file. Pushed to github and tried deployment but no progress at all.
````

Comment: error is self explanatory bump python version, also images of error etc should be edited as code